# corrupted python virtual environment after update

Tags: python, virtualenv

this winter I've been working on a Flask Application following [this tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world).
Today, hence after 3 months, I decided to work again on it, but all my set up seems corrupted.
The application started simply activating the virtualenv and calling `flask run`. 
As for today, the command returns:

```
No module named 'flask'
```

and so for `pip`, `pip3` etc. even if all these modules are in `venv/bin`.
My only guess is that since then, I updated python systemwide to Python 3.8.3rc1, which somehow became the default `python` in the venv as well, even if I was working in `python 3.7`. If that is the case, I wouldn't know how to fix this problem.
Do you have any suggestion?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you created your virtual environment (let's call it `v`), two things happened:

1. `v/bin/python` was a link to your system Python 3.7
2. `v/lib/python3.7` was created for packages installed to the virtual environment.

When you updated, the `v` link remained the same, but now it points to Python 3.8, which will look for a library directory named `python3.8`. Hence, your old Flask installation is invisible to the new Python.

Ideally, you wouldn't use your system Python for anything; install your own Python (under `/usr/local/` or something), so that instead of *upgrading* to a new version of PYthon, you can simply install a new version along side it. Then your virtual environment can continue using whatever version of Python it was created with.

That said, you should probably just recreate your virtual environment from scratch.

Comment: thank you for your answer.I just listed all python execs inside my /usr/bin folder and I can still find all the python versions that I used (including python 3.7). Is there any way to relink it? otherwise I'll simply recreate my virtual environment. Thank!

Comment: You might just be able to remove and recreate the symlink in your virtual environment's `bin` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the Pip
->> pip install --upgrade pip
and then install the falsk again 
->>pip install flask
and lemme know if it works

Comment: unfortunately pip does not work inside the virtual env anymore: ```No module named pip```. I cannot updated it